# Media Embed with Youtube not working - Error: Specified "type" attribute of "video/youtube" is not supported

Tags: jquery, youtube, mediaelement.js

I am officially stumped, I have done this several times before but this time I am getting an error that I cannot figure out.

So basically, I have the following code in my page...

```
<video id="youtube1" width="640" height="360">
    <source src="http://youtube.com/embed/Hr2Bc5qMhE4" type="video/youtube" >
</video>
```

Then the following in my header,

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('video').mediaelementplayer();
});
```

I have linked the stylesheet and the jquery and the javascript files, no issues there.

All files have been uploaded to the server and checked and double checked.

But when I load the page, I get the following error...

```
Specified "type" attribute of "video/youtube" is not supported. Load of media resource http://youtube.com/embed/Hr2Bc5qMhE4 failed.
```

My .htaccess contains all the addtypes needed I believe

```
AddType video/x-flv .flv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType application/x-mpegurl .m3u8
```

Comment: why the yt video ID on the error is different from the `source` tag? you may have some garbage code

Comment: Sorry its because I was troubleshooting while writing the question just to cover, ill fix that

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine http://jsfiddle.net/yTHrW/show/

Comment: I was able to get it to work with vimeo videos, but still no luck on the youtube side.  So it must be a server issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have get same error "Specified "type" attribute of "video/youtube" is not supported. Load of media resource http://youtube.com/embed/Hr2Bc5qMhE4 failed."

Steps:
1) I have download latest mediaelement using "https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/" link.
2) mediaelement downloaded folder I have search "flashmediaelement.swf".
3) Added this file on project folder.
4) clear browser cache and then run your project.